# Cannot read QR Code with ASCII characters using AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c, qr-code

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
unsigned char myKey[2];
myKey[0]=1;
myKey[1]=2;
if(metadataObjects == nil  || [metadataObjects count] ==0)
{
    qrCodeFrameView.frame=CGRectZero;
}
if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {
    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {
        Encoder *encoder=[[Encoder alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"0000-----%@",[metadataObj stringValue]);
        unsigned char buffer_to_decrypt=[metadataObj stringValue];
        [encoder tripledes_decrypt:buffer_to_decrypt lenght:sizeof(buffer_to_decrypt) key:myKey];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer_to_decrypt length:sizeof(buffer_to_decrypt)];
        NSLog(@"data = %@", data);
        NSString *result=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"-----<<<<result>>>>%@",result);
        AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObj=(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_videoPreviewLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:metadataObj];
        qrCodeFrameView.frame=barCodeObj.bounds;
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        [self stopReading];
        _isReading = NO;
    }
}}
```

Here I'm able to read normal QR Codes. But [metadataObj stringValue] is returning nil, when reading ASCII characters from QR Code. I use this to encrypt data in QR Code so that only my app can read my QR Code. How can I read ASCII characters?
this is my encrypted QR Code [QR Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Hay.png)

Comment: After downloading the app that can read them that you used (QR Bot), it seems to use `ZBarSDK` & `ZXingObjc`. I guess that's the one that make it work. It won't surprise me that the Apple's one read only UTF8. So a solution maybe would be to base64 transform it? Then it should be UTF8 compliant and translatable again to your needs (to an encrypted one, then you decifer with the encoding ASCII you want).

Comment: Yess, it worked, thanks a lot @Larme !!! Now I appreciate base64:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't surprise me that Apple's SDK only transform using UTF8 encoding.

After downloading the app on a old iTunes and exploring it, I found references to `ZXingObjc` and `ZBarSDK` which I guess are used to read the QRCode, that would explain why the app can read it and yours can't.

So you can either use these third party library, or if you want to keep using the Apple's one, here is a possible solution:

```
NSString <=> EncryptedString <=> Base64EncryptedString <=> QRCode
```

Or wait for Apple to gives instead of only `[metadataObj stringValue]`, `[metadataObj stringValueUsingEncoding:]`, or `[metadataObj rawData]`(that you can after used with `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[metadataObj rawData] encoding:NSASCIIEncoding]`).